# ASP.NET RazorPages: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm very new to ASP.NET and I'm trying some things out right now.
I try to make a simple dashboard right now which displays some set numbers, but I get this System.NullReferenceException
The whole day I try to fix this, but it keeps throwing this exception.

index.cshtml:

```c#
@model XSP.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel

              <img src="assets/images/plane-icon.png" alt="deliver-icon">
                                    </span>
                                    <h2>Errors</h2>
                                </div><!--/.icon-box-->
                                <h3>@Model.errors</h3>
                                <p>0 This Week</p>
                            </div><!--/.profile-state-->
                        </div><!--/.col-->
```

My HomeController where the values are getting filled:

```c#
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            DashboardViewModel dashboard = new DashboardViewModel();

            dashboard.onlineplayers = 1;
            dashboard.errors = 222;
            return View(dashboard);
        }
    }
```

And here's my ViewModel

```c#
    public  class DashboardViewModel
    {
        public  int onlineplayers { get; set; };
        public  int errors { get; set; };
    }
```

I already checked the other threads before I asked this question where the solution was always in the Controller adding return View(XX); but I have a return value.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: When debugging your code, what line throws the exception ?

Comment: I alredy saw that post and no it did not help me (maybe I'm just too stupid). This line throws the exception: `<h3>@Model.errors</h3>`

Comment: Try debugging `Index` method and see whether the `dashboard` object is being passed correctly. I think that the page you're rendering is not actually `Index` page, but some other. That's why you're getting `nullreference`

Comment: You mean in the HomeController? If yes, no it does not get passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, I think it resolves your issue.

you should ignore  `;` in your class.

```
 public  class DashboardViewModel
    {
        public  int onlineplayers { get; set; }
        public  int errors { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update**

The solution is just remove the `@page` keyword.For example a `Index.cshtml` razor page will get it's model from `Index.cshtml.cs` file method.

Comment: Hi, no it does not fix my problem. Error is same as before.

Comment: Pls, explain the difference between this  and PO code?

Comment: @Hakuryuu I updated my answer.please check

Comment: @Serge it's not different totally. just for experiment.

Comment: I already removed those. Still same error.

Comment: Can you add this line ```@using XSP.ViewModels```? in _Viewimports.cshtml?

Comment: @Hakuryuu my machine works perfectly in your code now.

Comment: I added `@using XSP.ViewModels` but it still throws the exception

Comment: rebuild your project, if not works then please share your ```index.cshtml``` all code.

Comment: Did not fix the issue. Full index.cshtml: https://pastebin.com/utww6Z6N

Comment: why you actually used this ```@page```.no need here. remove it into all of your views, ```@page``` then it works.

Comment: It was added automatically. When I remove it and compile it it says this: http://prntscr.com/139yz0h

Comment: please check your route. it's your routing problem. check ```startup.cs```.can you added extra Area in your application? and is your application asp.net core MVC ?

Comment: please check ```startup.cs```   ```app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });``` by the way,you have to obviously  remove ```@page```.

Comment: Yeah I just added that a few minutes ago. It catches now the controller and removing the @page fixed the issue!
Thank you!